# How to ask in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a line of code which asks a question and the user has to enter a number. The number is then stored as a variable and used throughout the rest of the script. Such as:

fit1 = "What is your fitness level?"
level = *the number the user had entered*

something like that. Can't really explain it properly

P.S. I'm writing my code out in gedit because thats what my uni uses.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Answer (score 1):

You can use a prompt like shown below:

```js
var n = prompt("Fitness level");
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.level = window.prompt('What is my fitness level?');
console.log(window.level); //save in glonal space of window
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Prompt command, and cast the string answer to type number :

```js
var number = parseInt(prompt('Give me a number', '0'));
alert('You said: ' + number);
```